# How do I get to show a random fragment?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

Ok, so the thing is that I want to create a button that links to a random fragment of my pageviewer-supported application. I googled a lot about this matter but I could not find something useful. I know that this may be a elemantary and easy to do thing but for my weak knowledge it is not. I appreciate any kind of help that I may get and I thank you all for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    //number_of_fragments must be replaced with number from your example.
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(number_of_fragments);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(randomNum);
    return rootView;
}
```